# How sort multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional PHP array each with a sub array that contains a list of states, their capitals, populations, and population ranks. for example the multidimensional array looks like

```
 $state_info = array(
'States' => array('utah','.....')
'Capitals' =>  array('Dallas','.....'),                 
'Population' => array(4779736,.....),
 'Ranks' => array(23,....)
);
```

My goal is to alternate sorting the columns by ascending, then descending and I cannot get any of the sort functions to work with the underlying code.

```
foreach($state_info as $key => $row )
{
    if($key == "States"){
        echo "<br>Sorting first column: ....<br>";
        foreach($row as $values){
            sort($values);
            echo "<br>".$values;
        }

    }
    else if($key == "Capitals"){
        echo "<br><br>Sorting second column: ....<br>";
        foreach($row as $values){
            sort($values);
            echo "<br>".$values;
        }
    }
    else if($key == "Population"){
        echo "<br><br>Sorting third column: ....<br>";
        foreach($row as $values){
            //sort values here
            sort($values);
            echo "<br>".$values;
        }
    }
    else if($key == "Ranks"){
        echo "<br><br>Sorting fourth column: ....<br>";
        foreach($row as $values){
            sort($values);
            echo "<br>".$values;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, I would recommend changing the if-else-if tree to a switch statement. It would make the code neater.  Second, for each key, first sort the array, and then go through the for-each loop to print the values.

Comment: This will never work you are sorting each individual key against itself....

Comment: well where would i put the sort statement so im not sorting the key against itself

Comment: I will post answer in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider switch statement as well

```
$state_info = array(
'States' => array('utah','zibra','aba'),
'Capitals' =>  array('Dallas','Zbcap','Abcap'),                 
'Population' => array(4779736,9090,2030),
 'Ranks' => array(23,24,2)
);

foreach($state_info as $key => $row )
{
    if($key == "States"){
        echo "<br>Sorting first column: ....<br>";

    sort($row);
    foreach($row as $values){
        echo "<br>".$values;
    }

}
else if($key == "Capitals"){
    echo "<br><br>Sorting second column: ....<br>";

    sort($row);
    foreach($row as $values){
        echo "<br>".$values;
    }
}
else if($key == "Population"){
    echo "<br><br>Sorting third column: ....<br>";

    //sort values here
    sort($row);
    foreach($row as $values){
        echo "<br>".$values;
    }
}
else if($key == "Ranks"){
    echo "<br><br>Sorting fourth column: ....<br>";

    sort($row);
    foreach($row as $values){
        echo "<br>".$values;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: using my current code this works great for sorting, i completely overlooked where i was performing the sort. Thanks!

Comment: what would be a good way to dump the original contents of the multidimensional array into a table like format? so that i can see the results as they are performed?

Comment: @user3236101 at the end of your code you can use `print_r($state_info)` or `var_dump($state_info)`

Comment: @user3236101 There is one thing I have to tell you. With the codes above, the original array `$state_info` will not be changed. In your first `foreach` you have to pass reference and that can be done with a simple `&` which means `foreach($state_info as $key => &$row )`

Comment: @user3236101 There is one small thing, if the answer actually solved your problem I would really appreciate if you mark it as accepted with that tick mark under voting area. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize array to

```
$states = array();
$Capitals= array();
$Population= array();
$Ranks= array();
```

When you start foreach($arr as $key => $data) loop you have to start pushing

```
array_push($states,$state_info['States']);
array_push($Capitals,$state_info['Capitals']);
array_push($Population,$state_info['Population']);
array_push($Ranks,$state_info['Ranks']);
```

Here $key is important, if you want to fetch 5th array element Then you have to jump key like $states[5], $Capitals[5], $Ranks[5], $Population[5]

While sorting any of the above array, maintain their indices(do not use any sorting on keys)...

This might give you an idea of doing better...

Comment: thanks this actually gave me a pretty good idea of what other option i could use.

Answer (score 0):

> I posted this js solution overlooking that it was a php question. I went to delete the post but noticed the OP commented on another answer about bringing in the data into a table. This answer may be useful for sorting on the client side.

Use this give it your array, the name of the key you want to sort and a true/false boolean to choose sort order. ascending or descending
It works for numbers or strings

```
var sortArray = function(array, key, desc) {
    //sortArray(array, string, boolean);
    //sort array by specific key, asc or desc - only handles strings, numbers
    if(desc == undefined) desc = false; //default to false if not set
    if(isNumeric(array[0][key])){
        //sort by number
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(!desc){
                return a[key] - b[key]; //sorts asc
            }else{
                return b[key] - a[key]; //sorts desc
            }
        });
    }else if(typeof array[0][key] == "string"){
        //sort by alpha;
        return array.sort(function(a, b){
            if(!desc){
                return a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : 1; //sorts asc
            }else{
                return a[key] < b[key] ? 1 : -1; //sorts desc
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("type unknown, no sorting done");
        return array;
    }
}

var isNumeric = function(num) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## One Way Sort

```
foreach($state_info as $key)
{
    switch ($key) {
        case 'States':
            arsort($state_info['States']); // high to low
            foreach ($state_info['States'] as $key2 => $value) echo $value;
            break;
        case 'Capitals':
            arsort($state_info['Capitals']); // high to low
            foreach ($state_info['Capitals'] as $key2 => $value) echo $value;
            break;
        case 'Population':
            arsort($state_info['Population']); // high to low
            foreach ($state_info['Population'] as $key2 => $value) echo $value;
            break;
        case 'Ranks':
            arsort($state_info['Ranks']); // high to low
            foreach ($state_info['Ranks'] as $key2 => $value) echo $value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$state_info = array(
'States' => array('Utah','AAA', 'XXX'),
'Capitals' =>  array('Dallas','BBB', 'ZZZ'),                 
'Population' => array(4779736, 1111111, 222222),
 'Ranks' => array(23, 12, 1)
);

function printA() {
global $asc;

foreach($asc as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ': <br/>';
  foreach($value as $info) {
     echo $info . '<br>'; 
  }   
  echo '<br>';
}   
}   

$asc = array_map(function($element) {sort($element); return($element);}, $state_info);

echo '<p><b>Asc</b></p>';
printA();

$asc = array_map(function($element) {rsort($element); return($element);}, $state_info);

echo '<p><b>Desc</b></p>';
printA();
?>
```